# Textures doesnt shown up with GLSL Shading

Tags: texturing

i have textured a modell and i wonder why when i change the shading option from multitexture to GLSL the textures will not shown up. what could be the reason for that?

[image: texturing]

Comment: And we all wonder HOW did you texture your model, which engine you used, materials setup, texturing method... please add details & images of your setup.

Comment: ok. i am using Blender v2.79. i have 3d view and uv image editor open. i select object in 3d view (viewport shading: texture)and unwarp it. then i open a png texture in the uv image editor and put the adjust size and position of the different faces and i see the result in the 3d view with multitexture shading on. when i change to GLSL the object become grey like the color of the standard material i think